# How to handle the pylint message: ID:W0612 Unused Variable

Tags: python, coding-style, pylint

I'm updating some code to PEP 8 standard using pylint. Part of the code is throwing the W0612 unused variable error but it's because it's using a module that returns (x,y) for example when only x is needed in this particular case, this is what's done.

```
(var_1, var_2) = func()

def func():
    a="a"
    b="b"
    return (a,b)
```

var_1 is then returned but var_2 is never used and therefore throws the error. How should I handle this? I'm thinking this

```
var = func()[0]
```

What is the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I believe that `a, dummy = func()` does the trick. Pylint allows (if I recall correctly) unused variables names that start with `_` or `dummy`, e.g. `dummy_index`.

You can configure this by passing `--dummy-variables-rgx` option to Pylint. This specifies the regex that catches dummy variable names.

From [Pylint 1.6.0 documentation](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html#id17):

> dummy-variables-rgx:
>
> A regular expression matching the name of dummy variables (i.e. expectedly not used).
>       Default: (_+[a-zA-Z0-9]*?$)|dummy

**Note**: Using `_` can indeed cause confusion (props: Sven Marnach). There's a convention to use single underscore as prefix for semi-private identifiers, the double underscore is of course the prefix for special Python methods and on top of that there's a convention to alias`gettext()` function as `_()` in programs that need localization as in `_("text to translate")`.

Comment: Yes that's perfect `unused_index` didn't work, `_unused_index` and `_index` did though. thanks for your help.

Comment: I recommend to use `dummy` over a mere `_` as a variable name.  The latter usually causes unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @Jacxel I was wrong about the `unused` prefix. This is what we used in a codebase I used to work on. The Pylint default is `dummy` or `_`.

Comment: If you don't like these conventions, I think you can add other alternatives by using a pylintrc file.  You can also disable pylint warnings on individual lines by adding a comment like `#pylint: disable=X0123` (see the [official documentation](http://www.logilab.org/card/pylint_manual)).

Comment: @SvenMarnach agreed. Edited to include this.

Comment: Alternatively, to make it so that `unused` and `dummy` are both acceptable prefixes for unused variables (but `_` isn't), modify the dummy variables line in `~/.pylintrc` to be: `dummy-variables-rgx=unused|dummy`.   Do this if it is more convenient for you than using the corresponding command line option.