# Silence PyLint warning about unused variables for string interpolation

Tags: python, pylint, unused-variables

The `say` module brings string interpolation to Python, like this:

```
import say

def f(a):
    return say.fmt("The value of 'a' is {a}")
```

However, PyLint complains that the variable 'a' is never used.  This is a problem because my code uses `say.fmt` extensively.  How can I silence this warning?

Comment: Does https://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message help?

Comment: If you really want to do this, create a local `.pylintrc` file which suppresses that warning.

Comment: Does say use `locals()` to get the args?  That seems hinky.

Comment: @JohnGordon. Yes, it does. And yes, it does.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Thanks, but I don't want to disable the *unused variable* warning for all variables.

Comment: Note that string interpolation is now included in Python 3.6

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, you can silence pylint warnings.

Here is one way:

```
import say

def f(a):
    # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    return say.fmt("The value of 'a' is {a}")
```

Alternatively, you can create a config file and add these lines to it:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=unused-argument
```

Reference:

- https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message
- https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#command-line-options

Comment: This statement will disable `unused-argument` check for the rest of the module. It's better to enable it after this function.

Answer (score 26):

One approach to silencing that message is to name or prefix the argument with `dummy` or `_`, as in:

```
import say

def f(_a):
    return say.fmt("The value of 'a' is {_a}")
```

See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107410/1080804

Comment: The downside of this method is that it changes the function signature, since in Python one can always call: `f(_a=1)`.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com I suppose you could just make the first line of the function be '_a=a' but that's pretty ick

Answer (score 9):

There is `disable-possibly-unused-variable` now (since [pylint 2.0 was released on 2018-07-15](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.0.html)), which one could ignore in files importing your `say` module:

> New **possibly-unused-variable** check added.
>
> This is similar to unused-variable, the only difference is that it is emitted when we detect a locals() call in the scope of the unused variable. The locals() call could potentially use the said variable, by consuming all values that are present up to the point of the call. This new check allows to disable this error when the user intentionally uses locals() to consume everything.
>
> For instance, the following code will now trigger this new error:
>
> ```
> def func():
>     some_value = some_call()
>     return locals()
> ```

The rationale for this check [explicitly includes your use case](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1909#issue-301993685), though it's noted that it's not a perfect solution:

> It would be great to have a separate check for unused variables if locals() is used in the same scope:
>
> ```
> def example_no_locals():
>   value = 42  # pylint: disable=unused-variable
>
> def exmaple_defined_before():
>   value = 42  # pylint: disable=possibly-unused-variable
>   print(locals())
>
> def exmaple_defined_after():
>   print(locals())
>   value = 42  # pylint: disable=unused-variable
> ```
>
> The benefit of this is that one can disable probably-unused-variable for a file (that has a lot of string formatting in it, or the config code example in #641) or the whole project without also loosing checks for unused-variable.

Answer (score 6):

I use this pattern:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
  _ = (a, b)  # unused: use these later
  return c + 1
```

It's less verbose than a waiver, I don't need to munge the keyword argument names, and I have a handy reminder to get back to using those variables later.

Comment: This should be voted higher. I was having the issue with monkey-patched methods, so I couldn't just change the argument names.

Comment: IMO this is the better than all the other current solutions because: (1.) it allows you to specifically disable the pylint warning for a,b and not c (in the future you may have d,e,f which you do not want to ignore) (2.) the solution is still one line of code (like `# pylint: disable=unused-argument`)

Answer (score 0):

We can resolve this issue by using "*" before our arguments
EXAMPLE-:
`def foo(a,b):`
was giving pylint issue i.e. 'a' (unused-argument) and 'b' (unused-argument), so I have added "*" before my arguments and it got resolved like
`def foo(_a,_b):`

Answer (score 0):

The `say.fmt` syntax seems to be extremely similar to [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals), which are now the recommended way to format strings in Python.

I'd write a small python script to automatically update your scripts (use git as backup), and replace `say.fmt("something {something}")` with `f"something {something}"`:

```
def f(a):
    return f"The value of 'a' is {a}"

print(f(5))
# The value of 'a' is 5
```

It will be cleaner, faster, won't need any external libray, won't require any PyLint hack, and you can then use rename features from your IDE.